# Android VideoView not working with older devices

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

I have an app which uses a video view to show live streaming. It works fine with my Galaxy S4 devices but it does not work on older devices or even other 4.0+ devices. 
I get a pop up warning saying: Cannot play video. Sorry, this video cannot be played

I am using an HTTP url to go to the streaming page.

```
   MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(parentActivity);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);

        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(auction.getVideoUrl());//"http://..../playlist.m3u8");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);

        videoView.setVideoURI(video);

        //videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                GEMLog.i(TAG, "video ready to be played " + auction.getVideoUrl());
                Log.i(TAG, "video ready to be played " + auction.getVideoUrl());
                videoView.start();
                if (delegate != null)
                {
                    delegate.videoReady();
                }

            }

        });
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think that protocol was supported on older Android versions.

Comment: any ideas on how to implement video view with that format on devices 2.1+ ?